# Insert content from MySQL to paragraph using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, dom

I am trying to insert ads to my $article_content using PHP, I need to place the ad code according the paragraph number.

When I do a select to my MySQL I got this structure:

ID_ARTICLE | AD CODE | PARAGRAPH

Probably the most of articles gonna have 04 rows of data (04 ads), something like:

1 | adcode/adcode | 0 
1 | adcode/adcode | 1 
1 | adcode/adcode | 3 
1 | adcode/adcode | 5

So this is my code:

```
$pdo = ConectarSite();

$sql3 = "
SELECT
   art.id,
   ab.adcode,
   ap.paragraph 
FROM
   artigos art 
   LEFT JOIN
      anuncios_artigo aa 
      ON art.id = aa.id_artigo 
   LEFT JOIN
      anuncios_bloco ab 
      ON aa.id_anuncios_bloco = ab.id 
   LEFT JOIN
      anuncios_posicao ap 
      ON aa.id_anuncios_posicao = ap.id 
WHERE
   art.id = :id
";
$stmt3 = $pdo->prepare($sql3);
$stmt3->execute(['id' => '1']);


$article_content = '<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been</p>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($article_content);

while($row3 = $stmt3->fetch()) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $row3['paragraph']; $i++) {
        $p = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
        if ($i == $row3['paragraph']) {
            $ads = $doc->createElement('div', $row3['adcode']);
            $p->insertBefore($ads);
        }
    }

}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

I don't know how to create the for correctly

Comment: You should create, fill and output your `DOMDocument` outside the main `while ()` loop, only the inserting of the ads should be inside the loop.

Comment: Hi Kiko Sofware, thanks alot for your time, could you please gime an code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what I meant when I said:

> You should create, fill and output your `DOMDocument` outside the main
> while ()` loop, only the inserting of the ads should be inside the
> loop.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($article_content);

foreach ($adverts as $row3) {
    $paragraphs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
    for ($i = $paragraphs->length; --$i >= 0; ) {
        $paragraph = $paragraphs->item($i);
        if ($i + 1 == $row3['paragraph']) {
            $ads = $doc->createElement('div', $row3['adcode']);
            $paragraph->parentNode->insertBefore($ads, $paragraph);
        }
    }
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Notice that the paragaphs items run from 0 to n-1, and since your paragraph numbering runs from 1 to n, a correction is needed.

Comment: Ok, let me run the code to see what really happens. One moment.

Comment: Sorry it works, I Just need to figure out where to place the paragraph number to insert in the right place, you'r right about the ($i == 1)

Comment: Ok, yes, when I tested it, it seemed to work as well.

Comment: You will see the paragraphs will not be duplicated but the "ad code" will be

Comment: Indeed, all ads are inserted after the first paragraph.

Comment: I am thinking about the right place to place the paragraph data from MySQL

Comment: I think `if ($i == $row3['paragraph']) ...`, or something similar, is what you want.

Comment: I think we almost there haha, trying to do a test to insert 2 ads, one before the first paragraph and another after the third paragraph

Comment: Hey, thanks alot for your help it was so obviously dam, I just got one more question if you can answer me of course, I think the insertBefore ( ) isn't working correctly, If I set before the paragraph "1" it inserts after the paragraph one... lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244145/discussion-between-sophie-and-kiko-software).

Comment: Sorry, I was gone for a little while. `foreach` doesn't work right if you manipulate the dom object inside its loop. Use a `for` loop instead. See the comment by: [drichter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#83178).

Comment: No problem, thanks alot for your help, I am trying to figure out how to make the 'for' loop works with my code, it seens wrong : "for ($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $p)" I don't work too much with the 'for' hehe

Comment: Scroll up a bit on the PHP manual page I pointed to, and you will see an example of a `for` loop.

Comment: Could you check the updated question code?

Comment: I really don't know how to use "for"

Comment: @Sophie: I updated my answer. Hopefully that will work for you. `for` loops are very basic .... it's probably time to learn a bit more PHP before trying more difficult stuff.

Comment: I am getting error 500 with the new code

Comment: The last line its wrong, it is: $paragraph->insertBefore($ads); that was generating the error 500

Comment: And after fix it, I saw its the same result than using foreach hahaha... it doesn't insert the ads before to first paragraph, only starting under the first one

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. I used a correction: `$i + 1`, what happens if you, intsead, just you `$i`?

Comment: Keep the same problem, It won't let me insert the adcode before the first paragraph, I am doing a test with 2 rows in MySQL (1 paragraph and 3 paragraph) the number 3 works correctly, but the number 1 appears after the first paragraph

Comment: @Sophie Ok, I tested the code again. From what I can tell `insertBefore()` was not used in the correct way. I changed my answer. You can [find my test code here](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/38628).